# Make links in existing PDF using python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to make existing text in a PDF links to another PDF, or concatenate the PDFs and then link internally. There would be 100 + links so I do not want to do this by hand.

I tried using pypdf, this worked to get the pages the links should lead to, but I do not know how to make the text links.

So: How to make links in an existing PDF using python?